# google analytics javascript application

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have a javascript application (no refreshes).

I'm trying to setup google analytics to track events for each user, so that it would be possible to see which user performed which event in the application.

I think I'm supposed to set a custom var of a session type? But not sure how to go about it. I'm looking for an example, thanks.

The question is:

How do I set a session level user so that all the events that that user initiates are set as that by the user. I have the user's username saved as a javascript variable. I just want to attach that variable to the google analytics session.

Comment: How are you identifying a user?

Comment: @jk. it should be either their username or 'anon'

Comment: GA doesn't have any concept of the user accessing your page. Your best bet is to stick it in the `action` (third) parameter. Of course, this will create a ton of unique actions. Alternatively, you could put a numeric user ID as the `value` parameter.

Comment: @GGG Username or User ID shouldn't be put in at all. It is a violation of [GA's TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html).

Comment: @jk. are you referring to section 7 of their TOS? I think you are right about username, but I'm not sure user ID qualifies as personally identifiable.

Comment: @GGG If user ID identifies a single user, it does violate it. Anything that you could use to identify a specific user to you or anyone else violates that part of policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's their username then that is a violation of [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html). See number 7 PRIVACY.

Custom vars can be used to determine user type and/or login status. See [Session-level Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples)

> For example, if your website offers users the ability to login, you can use a custom variable scoped to the session level for user login status. In that way, you can segment visits by those from logged in members versus anonymous visitors.

Example:

> While the username or user ID is not directly PII, if it is used to tie to a person from a backend system…that’s a violation of the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need customer event tracking, like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

Check out the [Google Analytics API Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

The key point is, you don't necessarily need to tie a Google Analytics event to a page load; simpy push events from your function calls.

Comment: That was not in your original question; see @jk -- as an alternative, check our MixPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can record custom events with something like:

```
_gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction);
```

And, if you want to track the "events" as page views:

```
_gat._getTrackerByName()._trackPageview(track_url);
```

[Google's Tracking Basics (Asynchronous Syntax)](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html)

Comment: You're already doing what? The trackEvent or trackPageview? Tracking events doesn't provide an easy way to view a user's progression through your app which is why I suggested the trackPageview. With trackPageview, Google already handles tracking how a particular user progresses through the system.

Comment: I'm already doing both. Certain events, like 'purchase' have events attached, going to pages have track pageview and the url. The question is how do I make sure that these events all follow the same user: some kind of `setUserName(Harry)` and then I would be able to see that it was Harry that did so and so event.